# can't scrape website data using multiple Node.js libs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web-scraping

I want to get some data for website like https://www.citrix.com/, https://www.adobe.com
but the response mostly something like that I use Cheerio, Axios, Puppeteer, Playwright Request and many other libraries(but I don't like the part of opening the page in a browser  for some libs like puppeteer and playwright), ***is it good idea to switch Python or will be the same result?***

```
LoadedCheerio {
  length: 0,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      type: 'root',
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *1]
  },
  prevObject: <ref *2> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      type: 'root',
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  }
}
```

This's one of the functions for scraping using request there's another function using Axios but it's almost the same result

```
const scrapeDataFromWebsite = () => {
      request('citrix.com', function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    
          //   console.log(html);
          const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
          console.log($);
          var companyDetails = {
    
            compnanyName: ",",
            emailContact: [],
            phoneNumber: [],
            companyAbout: [],
            compnayWebsite: "",
            industry: "",
          }
          $('title').each((i, ele) => {
    
            const title = $(ele).text();
            companyDetails.compnanyName = title;
    
          });
    
          $('section').each((i, ele) => {
    
            const aboutSection = $(ele).text();
            console.log("aboutSection" + aboutSection);
            companyDetails.companyAbout.push(aboutSection);
    
          }); 
        });
    
    }
```

Comment: If what you need to scrape is generated by JavaScript you'll need something that can run js, like puppeteer, etc

Comment: @Phix which is need to open the website page in a browser window? so can I skip the part of the browser window somehow and scrape the data because the application is a list of website links and it's gonna go through each one.

Comment: @Phix Can I ask something about combining NodeJS and ReactJS together, I already have the project and created a server folder in the root dir of React App so when I try to run and NodeJS function inside ReactJS it says errors in importing files from outside, So one solutions is using ExpressJS so being in rush should I move these files to `src/`  or using `ExpressJS` in regard the app is need to be high secured.

Comment: Your second question is a whole other issue, I don't know from the context of your comment. If by "somehow skipping the browser window", sure, run it in headless mode.